# Row Scanning and Delay for Automatic Sms Sending in VB2012

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have a MS SQL Linked-Server (from Mysql) - generated Table TBL containing

```
*Index
*StdNo
*MobileNo
```

And I have a VB2012 code for SMS sending:

```
Private Sub cmdsend_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdsend.Click
    Try
        If SerialPort1.IsOpen Then
            With SerialPort1
                .Write("AT" & vbCrLf)
                .Write("AT+CMGF=1" & vbCrLf)
                .Write("AT+CMGS=" & Chr(34) & TextBox1.Text & Chr(34) & vbCrLf)
                .Write(RichTextBox1.Text & Chr(26))


            End With
        Else
            MsgBox("Error on the port selected")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Where TextBox1.Text is the textbox where number is actually manually inputted
and RichTextBox1.Text is the message that will be sent.

What I wanted is to create a code that will automatically select each row of the table TBL for the MobileNo and then sends SMS. Since the VB code is not really for Bulk messaging, my idea is to create a loop that will scan each row, get each MobileNo, sends the message, then delay for a few second before the next row scan. I don't even know if it is possible. But I think it is, I just don't know how to come up with the loop and I don't even know how to create the connection between the database. Does anybody have any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: what sort of table is TBL? is it a database table or excel or a csv?

Comment: it's a database table from linked server MS SQL

Comment: start my getting hold of the ADO.Net driver for MySQL then look at the SQLconnection and SQLcommand class

Answer (score 0):

may be you can use this code:

```
Private Sub cmdsend_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdsend.Click
    Try
        If SerialPort1.IsOpen Then
            With SerialPort1
                .Write("AT" & vbCrLf)
                .Write("AT+CMGF=1" & vbCrLf)
                .Write("AT+CMGS=" & Chr(13) 
.Write(TextBox1.Text)
                .Write(Chr(26))
            End With
        Else
            MsgBox("Error on the port selected")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```